# Java How can I break a while loop under a switch statement?

Tags: java, while-loop, break

I have a homework to implement a simple testing application, below is my current code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{

private static int typing;

public static void main(String argv[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Testing starts");
    while(sc.hasNextInt()){
        typing = sc.nextInt();
        switch(typing){
            case 0:
              break; //Here I want to break the while loop
            case 1:
              System.out.println("You choosed 1");
              break;
            case 2:
              System.out.println("You choosed 2");
              break;
            default:
              System.out.println("No such choice");
        }
    }
      System.out.println("Test is done");
    }
}
```

What I want to do now is that when `0` is pressed, it means that the user wants to quit the test, then I break the `while loop` and print `Test is done`, but it doesn't work like that, I know the reason might be that the `"break"` breaks the `switch`, how can I let it break the `while loop` instead?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You can `label` your while loop, and `break` the `labeled loop`, which should be like this:

```
loop: while(sc.hasNextInt()){
    typing = sc.nextInt();
    switch(typing){
        case 0:
          break loop; 
        case 1:
          System.out.println("You choosed 1");
          break;
        case 2:
          System.out.println("You choosed 2");
          break;
        default:
          System.out.println("No such choice");
    }
}
```

And the `label` can be any word you want, for example `"loop1"`.

Comment: "loop" is a poor/boring choice of label. Funnier choices include "up", "out", "stuff", "theBank" and "dance".

Comment: Jokes aside, giving the loop a slightly more informative label (in your case, perhaps `scanner`), allows the breaks to look like `break scanner` (stop scanner).

Comment: @noamtm that wasn't obvious, so thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 14):

You need a boolean variable e.g. `shouldBreak`.

```
    boolean shouldBreak = false;
    switch(typing){
        case 0:
          shouldBreak = true;
          break; //Here I want to break the while loop
        case 1:
          System.out.println("You choosed 1");
          break;
        case 2:
          System.out.println("You choosed 2");
          break;
        default:
          System.out.println("No such choice");
    }
    if (shouldBreak) break;
```

Answer (score 5):

Put the while inside a function and when you press 0 instead of break just `return`. For example :

```
    import java.util.*;

public class Test{

private static int typing;

public static void main(String argv[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    func(sc);
      System.out.println("Test is done");
    }
}

public static void func(Scanner sc) {


    System.out.println("Testing starts");
    while(sc.hasNextInt()){
        typing = sc.nextInt();
        switch(typing){
            case 0:
              return; //Here I want to break the while loop
            case 1:
              System.out.println("You choosed 1");
              break;
            case 2:
              System.out.println("You choosed 2");
              break;
            default:
              System.out.println("No such choice");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How to terminate inner menu ?

**Example Code :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //used to get input
        int option1, option2 = 0;
        boolean loop_terminate = true; //flag used to terminate inner while loop

        //Main Menu
        while (true) {
            //Main Menu options
            System.out.println("1.Option 1");
            System.out.println("2.Option 2");
            System.out.println("3.Option 3");
            System.out.println("4.Option 4");
            System.out.println("5.Exit main menu");

            System.out.print("Please enter your choice : ");
            option1 = input.nextInt();

            switch (option1) {

                case 1:
                       //do something here    
                    break;
                case 2:
                       //do something here 
                    break;
                case 3:

                    while (loop_terminate) {
                        //Inner menu options
                        System.out.println("1.Inner Menu option 1");
                        System.out.println("2.Inner Menu option 2");
                        System.out.println("3.Inner Menu option 3");
                        System.out.println("4.Return to Main Menu");

                        System.out.print("Please enter your choice : ");
                        option2 = input.nextInt();
                        switch (option2) {

                            case 1:
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                loop_terminate = false; //this will terminate inner menu
                                break;
                            default:
                                System.out.println("Invalid option");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break; //never forget to add this break statement
                case 4:
                      break;
                case 5:
                    return; //terminate outer menu

                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid option");
            }
        }

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relatively simple way to do it!

Since you want to break the while loop if the value assigned to `typing` is 0, the easiest thing to do would be to check the value of `typing`, even before entering the switch-case statement.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{
    private static int typing;

    public static void main(String argv[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Testing starts");
    
        while(sc.hasNextInt()){
            typing = sc.nextInt();
        
            if (typing == 0){
                break;
            } 
        
            else{
                switch(typing){
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("You chose 1");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("You chose 2");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("No such choice");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Test is done");
    }
}
```