# How to continue to next loop from a switch satement which is inside the loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, switch-statement

In my project i have a loop that is a simulation of a choice menu and when the user chooses  a number i want to go to the next loop but that is a part of a switch statement that is inside the loop.
My code is:

```
while(entrychoice!=8){     

    String alphabet= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";  //tyxaio onoma    

       String   onoma = "";

      Random random = new Random();
      int randomLen = 1+random.nextInt(9);
    for(int p = 0; p < randomLen; p++) {
      char c = alphabet.charAt(random.nextInt(26));
       onoma+=c;
            }

            //Random rand=new Random();//this.kratisid=kratisid; kai stin main bazo random
            //int kratisid=rand.nextInt(500)+100;//Παραγει τυχαιο κωδικο κρατησης μεταξυ 100 και 500




 int kratisid = getRandomInt();  //dimiourgia monadikou kai tyxaiou                                    kratisid

    Random rand1=new Random();
    int afixi=rand1.nextInt(30)+1;//tyxaia mera afixis se ena mina

    Random rand2=new Random();
    int mdiam=rand2.nextInt(30)+1;//tyxaies meres diamonis se ena domatio

    Random rand3=new Random();
    int atoma=rand3.nextInt(4)+1;

    Domatio d=null;//reference to the domatio pou egine kratisi


    reservation r=new reservation(onoma,kratisid,afixi,mdiam,atoma,d);
    //r.antistoixisidtodom(d,dom);

   Hotel1.addkratisianyroom(r);//prosthiki  tyxaias kratisis r se tyxaio domatio

   //25% pithanotita gia tyxaia akyrosi kratisis
   Random randprob=new Random();
   int prob=randprob.nextInt(4)+1;//prob is the probability of cancelling a random kratisi
   if (prob==1)//25%
   {  //epilogi tyxaias kratisis apo tin lista kratiseon Rlist gia akyrosi
        Random randomGeneratorList=new Random();
        int index=randomGeneratorList.nextInt(Rlist.size())+0;//+0;

       int kratisiFRCID=Hotel1.Rlist.get(index).kratisid;//kratisiFRCid means kratisiForRandomCancel ID
        Hotel1.cancelkratisi(kratisiFRCID);//Rlist.get(index).cancel....
    }



         Scanner scanchoice = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Enter \"1\", \"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\",\"6\",\"7\"or\"8\"");
          if(scanchoice.hasNextInt()){
        entrychoice = scanchoice.nextInt();
    }
  switch(entrychoice)
  {
     case 1:
     continue;
     break;**
    }
```

}

Note that the code continues but is huge and the other options are not the matter.As you see in case1 of the switch statement i want if the user inputs 1 to go to the next loop but the compiler says that break; will never be executed which is something that disrupts my switch statement.Please suggest how to go to next loop with a switch statement and user input as i have done here.Thx in advance.

Comment: If you have another question, ask it as a separate question, with its own title, answers, votes, comments, etc. Nobody will see it here.

Comment: @davidxxx I don' know how exactly you expect me to respond to a deleted post, but the first sentence of it is incorrect. `continue` can be used anywhere inside a loop, including `switch` statements.

Comment: @ EJP Sorry.I definitively deleted.Indeed you are right.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is right, `break` is never reached. All you need to do is removing it:

```
switch(entrychoice) {
    case 1:
        continue;
    case 2:
        ...
        break;
}
```

The reason for having `break` is to end the `case` by sending execution to the end of the `switch`. Since `continue` also ends the `switch` by sending execution to a different point of your program, `break` becomes unreachable, so Java compiler insists on removing it.

Same goes for other constructs that break execution: you do not need a `break` after a `return` or `throw` inside a `switch`.

Comment: also sorry for asking again i have break; break; in the last switch statement so as to my programm to exit the genneral while loop if i leave only one break; i exit the loop right?

Comment: @GeorgeJ `break` inside a `switch` breaks the `switch`, not the loop. [Here is Q&A explaining how to exit a loop from inside a `switch`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22823427/335858).